# Responsive Bootstrap won't precompile

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm not too familiar with the inner workings of HTML. I depend on Bootstrap a little too much to work its magic for me, so I finally found a place where I'm completely stumped. I need to make the views for my app responsive to detect the resolution of the screens of devices connecting to it. On my local machine, this worked out just fine. I added in the third `stylesheet_link_tag` to my `layout/application.html.haml` file, as you can see below, as well as the `%meta` line following it.

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title WallyWorld
    = stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all"
    = stylesheet_link_tag    "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
    = stylesheet_link_tag    "assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css", :rel => 'stylesheet/less'
    = javascript_include_tag "application"
    = csrf_meta_tags
    %meta{:content => "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0", :name => "viewport"}
  %body
    // The rest...
```

Again, a lot of this doesn't make sense to me. Just following along with the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive) as best I can.

Everything works fine on my local machine with this in effect. However, when I `cap deploy` it and start up the `unicorn` server on the production box, I get the following error:

```
2013-08-06 12:57:54 FATAL -- 
ActionView::Template::Error (assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css isn't precompiled):
  4:     %title WallyWorld
  5:     = stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all"
  6:     = stylesheet_link_tag    "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
  7:     = stylesheet_link_tag    "assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css", :rel => 'stylesheet/less'
  8:     = javascript_include_tag "application"
  9:     = csrf_meta_tags
  10:     %meta{:content => "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0", :name => "viewport"}
app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:7:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_haml__3068307506204356330_32376380'
```

Ok, great. `bootstrap-responsive.css` isn't precompiled. Well, I don't actually know how to do that manually. I tried to download my own custom version of Bootstrap, as suggested by [this article](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/11/12/how-to-use-twitter-bootstrap-to-create-a-responsive-website-design/), but I'm even more confused now. I have no idea how to get any of that stuff working at all.

Any suggestions or explanations as to what the actual process is to get this stuff working would be great. It's strangely difficult to find an explanation on this, at least in terms that I can understand.

==== Edit to add in production.rb ====

```
Wallyworld::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Defaults to nil and saved in location specified by config.assets.prefix
  # config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # See everything in the log (default is :info)
  # config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  config.assets.precompile += %w( assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css )

  # Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable threaded mode
  # config.threadsafe!

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  # config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
end
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't have to put the paths in the `stylesheet_link_tag` like this. Just do:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'bootstrap-responsive' %>
```

In your `config/envinronments/production.rb` file, find the relevant setting:

`# config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )`

uncomment it and add the file which isn't precompiled in the array:

`config.assets.precompile += %w( bootstrap-responsive.css )`

Comment: Adding in `bootstrap-responsive.css` and `assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css` still gives me the same error.

Comment: Can you post the whole `production.rb` file? Are you deploying on Heroku? Does your Capfile precompile assets when you're deploying?

Comment: I added the file. No, I'm deploying to a server I own. Also, in case it helps, I can't run the app on my local machine anymore. I was moving around my bootstrap files and can't get the original app to show up anymore at all. Everything is complaining about the `bootstrap-responsive.css` file now.

Comment: It doesn't run even in development? What error do you get? btw you have it wrong in your file, it should be `bootstrap-responsive.css`. You can also precompile the assets locally if you want by `rake assets:precompile`.

Comment: Sorry, just thought to check Development again. It works fine there. It's the production environment that's messed up. To answer your question from earlier, yes the Capfile precompiles the assets. But I can't even manually compile my assets on my local machine and have it boot in production. Always fails. I changed the `production.rb` file back to just `bootstrap-responsive.css` and it's still throwing the error that it's not precompiled. I also manually ran the assets:precompile task for production. Hmm...

Comment: Updated my initial answer, use the stylesheet_link_tag as I've mentioned.

Comment: Do I need to keep the `:rel` option? Dunno what it means/does, but my Bootstrap stuff is using less.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34935/discussion-between-agis-and-brad-rice)